# Dynamically add where clauses to a cursor in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I have plsql procedure which accepts certain parameters e.g. v_name, v_country, v_type.

I wish to have a cursor with a select statement like this:

```
select column from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.name = v_name
and t1.country = v_country
and t1.id = t2.id
and t2.type = v_type
```

If certain parameters are empty can I only add the relevant where clauses to the cursor? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to use this is with DBMS_SQL.

You create a string that represents your SQL statement.  You still use bind variables.  It's painful.

It goes something like this (I haven't compiled this, but it should be close) :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_country( v_name  t1.country%TYPE,
                                         v_type  t2.type%TYPE)  /* Hmm, column called type? */
DECLARE
  v_SQL         varchar2(2000);
  v_select          INTEGER;   /* "Pointer" to a DBMS_SQL select statement */
  v_execute         INTEGER;

BEGIN
  v_SQL := 'select column from table1 t1, table2 t2 ||
           'where t1.id = t2.id';

  IF v_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' AND t1.country = :v_name'
  END IF;

  IF v_type IS NOT NULL THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' AND t2.type = :v_type';
  END IF;

  /* Setup Cursor */
  v_select := dbms_sql.open_cursor;     
  dbms_sql.parse( v_select, v_SQL, DBMS_SQL.native);

  IF v_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    dbms_sql.bind_variable( v_select, ':v_name', v_name );
  END IF;

  IF v_type IS NOT NULL THEN
    dbms_sql.bind_variable( v_select, ':v_type', v_type );
  END IF;

  DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_select, 1, v_column);  /* This is what we have selected */

  /* Return value from EXECUTE is undefined for a SELECT */     
  v_execute := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE( v_select );

  IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS( v_select ) > 0 THEN

    /* A row was found  
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE( v_select, 1, v_column);

    /* Tidy Up */
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_select);

    RETURN v_ID_address;

  ELSE

     DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_select);

     /* No row */
     RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF DBMS_SQL.IS_open(v_select) THEN
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_select);
      END IF;
      RAISE;
END;
```

This approach is so painful compared to just writing the SQL inline that unless you have heaps of columns sometimes it's just easier writing a couple of different versions using this syntax:

```
FOR r IN (SELECT blah FROM blah WHERE t1 = v_t1) LOOP
   func( r.blah );
END LOOP;
```

Comment: a column called type? ... don't ask! :(

Thanks a lot for this, it looks like the way i have to do it.

Answer (score 4):

It's not directly what you're asking, but it may be an acceptable solution:

```
select column from table1 t1, table2 t2
where
    (v_name is null or t1.name = v_name)
and (v_country is null or t1.country = v_country)
and t1.id = t2.id
and (v_type is null or t2.type = v_type)
```

Comment: For a limited number of parameters I think this is the best solution.  Dynamic methods are more general but also require more processing and are harder to maintain.

Comment: This can result in bad plans being generated by Oracle.  Remember it's going to have one plan for this statement.  It's going to have trouble using any indexes on t2.type or t1.name.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to build up your query as a string then use [execute immediate](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "build up your query" this can be a SQL injection bug

Answer (score 2):

The **best** way to do this would be to use Oracle's Application Context feature, best defined as best performance and security.

The **faster** way would be what hamishmcn suggested, using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  I'd choose that over WW's suggestion of DBMS_SQL **every time**.

Another way that's **quickest to write** but won't perform as well would be something like this:

```
select column from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.name = nvl(v_name, t1.name)
and t1.country = nvl(v_country, t1.country)
and t1.id = t2.id
and t2.type = nvl(v_type, t2.type)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use dbms_sql to solve this problem
and you can still use normal cursor by using a ref cursor.

Sample:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE cursor_ref IS REF CURSOR;
  c1 cursor_ref;
  r1 table1.column%type;
BEGIN
  l_sql := 'select t1.column from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id ';
  if v_name is not null then
    l_sql := l_sql||' and t1.name = '||v_name ;
  end if;
  if v_country is not null then
    l_sql := l_sql||' and t1.country = '||v_country';
  end if;
  if v_type is not null then  
    l_sql := l_sql||' and t2.type = '||v_type';
  end if;
  open c1 for l_sql;
  loop
      fetch c1 into r1;
      exit when c1%notfound;
      -- do something
  end loop;
  close c1;
end;
/
```

You can make this better by binding the variables with the command 'using' like this:

```
open c1 for l_sql using v_name, v_country;
```